# When constructing a pyarrow dataset with `FileSystemDataset.from_paths`, how do I specify partitions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a list of CSV files in a google bucket organized like `gs://bucket/some_dir/{partition_value}/filename`. I want to create a `pyarrow.Dataset` from a list of URIs like this (which is a subset of files in `some_dir`).

How do I do this and extract `partition_value` as a column?

So far I have:

```py
import gcsfs
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.csv
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from pyarrow.fs import FSSpecHandler, PyFileSystem

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
schema = pa.schema([("gene_id", pa.string()), ("raw_count", pa.float32()), ("scaled_estimate", pa.float32())])

# these data are publicly accessible, btw
uris = [
    "gs://gdc-tcga-phs000178-open/0b8b258e-1671-4f86-82e7-59b12ad40d9c/unc.edu.4c243ea9-dfe1-42f0-a887-3c901fb38542.2477720.rsem.genes.results",
    "gs://gdc-tcga-phs000178-open/c8ee8367-c529-4dd6-98b4-fde57991134b/unc.edu.a64ae1f5-a189-4173-be13-903bd7637869.2476757.rsem.genes.results",
    "gs://gdc-tcga-phs000178-open/78354f8d-5ce8-4617-bba4-79614f232e97/unc.edu.ac19f7cf-670b-4dcc-a26b-db0f56377231.2509607.rsem.genes.results",
]

dataset = ds.FileSystemDataset.from_paths(
    uris,
    schema,
    format=ds.CsvFileFormat(parse_options=pa.csv.ParseOptions(delimiter="\t")),
    filesystem=PyFileSystem(FSSpecHandler(fs)),
    # partitions=["bucket", "file_gcs_id"],
    # root_partition="gdc-tcga-phs000178-open",
)

dataset.to_table()
```

this gives me a nice table with fields in my schema.

but, i'd like `partition_key` to be another field in my dataset. i'm guessing i need:

1. to add this as a field to my schema and
2. to add something when calling `FileSystemDataset.from_paths`

i tried fiddling with `root_partition`, but got an error that the string i provided isn't a `pyarrow.Expression` (no idea what that is). also i tried specifying `partitions` but i get `ValueError: The number of files resulting from paths_or_selector must be equal to the number of partitions.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During *dataset discovery* filename information is used (along with a specified partitioning) to generate "guarantees" which are attached to fragments.  For example, when we see the file `foo/x=7/bar.parquet` and we are using "hive partitioning" we can attach the guarantee `x == 7`.  These guarantees are stored as "expressions" for various reasons we don't need to discuss at the moment.

Two solutions jump to mind.  First, you could create the guarantees yourself and attach them to your paths (this is what the `partitions` argument represents in the `from_paths` method).  The expression should be `ds.field("column_name") == value`.

Second, you could allow the dataset discovery process to run as normal.  This will generate all the fragments you need (and some you don't), with the guarantees already attached.  Then you could trim down the list of fragments to your desired list of fragments and create a dataset from that.

> (I'm guessing I need) to add this as a field to my schema

Yes.  In both of the above approaches you will want to make sure your partitioning column(s) are added to your schema.

Here is a code example showing both approaches:

```
import shutil

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow.fs as fs

shutil.rmtree('my_dataset', ignore_errors=True)

table = pa.Table.from_pydict({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'part': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
    })

ds.write_dataset(table, 'my_dataset', partitioning=['part'], format='parquet')

print('# Created by dataset factory')
partitioning = ds.partitioning(schema=pa.schema([pa.field('part', pa.string())]))
dataset = ds.dataset('my_dataset',partitioning=partitioning)
print(dataset.to_table())
print()

desired_paths = [
    'my_dataset/a/part-0.parquet'
]

# Note that table.schema used below includes the partitioning
# column so we've added that to the schema.
print('# Created from paths')
filesystem = fs.LocalFileSystem()
dataset_from_paths = ds.FileSystemDataset.from_paths(
    desired_paths,
    table.schema,
    format=ds.ParquetFileFormat(),
    filesystem=filesystem)
print(dataset_from_paths.to_table())
print()

print('# Created from paths with explicit partition information')
dataset_from_paths = ds.FileSystemDataset.from_paths(
    desired_paths,
    table.schema,
    partitions=[
        ds.field('part') == "a"
    ],
    format=ds.ParquetFileFormat(),
    filesystem=filesystem)
print(dataset_from_paths.to_table())
print()

print('# Created from discovery then trimmed')
trimmed_fragments = [frag for frag in dataset.get_fragments() if frag.path in desired_paths]
trimmed_dataset = ds.FileSystemDataset(trimmed_fragments, dataset.schema, dataset.format, filesystem=dataset.filesystem)
print(trimmed_dataset.to_table())
```

Comment: thanks @Pace :) unfortunately this is not working for me. i adapted your code to my data source for `from_paths` (a list of URIs of google cloud storage objects), and I can't get pyarrow to store subdirectory text as a field. I added a string field to my schema, but it always shows up as `null`. I made an example here at a github gist. the bucket is publicly accessible; you just need a credentialed gcsfs.GcsFileSystem object to run the same code. https://gist.github.com/grisaitis/71e93e514477d7da7f8cedbcf9748f85 does anything stand out to you in that example of what i'd need to change?

Comment: In your expressions you have `file_gdc_id` and in your schema you have `file_gcs_id`